# cross-reference to a rotated table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, center

In my doc I have few rotated tables, but I face an issue - \ref in text to the tables doesn't work - it shows ??

What I am doind wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
    %
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\counterwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage[margin=5pt,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,
labelsep=endash,format=hang]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{center}
        \caption{My sample table}
        \begin{turn}{90}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        A   & B  & C   \\
        100 & 10 & 1   \\
        1   & 10 & 100
    \end{tabular}
        \end{turn}
\end{center}
\label{tabble:rotar}
\end{table}

My table \ref{tabble:rotar} has no reference in the text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\label` goes after `\caption` here the `center` env shields it from the `\label`, so move the `\label` up after `\caption` where it belongs

Comment: It's an excellent idea to always issue the `\label` directive immediately after, and certainly within the same environment as, the `\caption` directive. For your table, I would further recommend that you replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and get rid of the `\end{center} statement.